# Mule : Print Key and Value in ForEach

Tags: foreach, hashmap, mule

I want to print both key and value in ForEach. I am able to get the Keyset but not individual key.

```
<set-variable variableName="fileContents" value="#[message.payload]" />

<foreach collection="#[message.payload]">
    <logger message="#[fileContents.keySet()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <logger message="#[message:payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

</foreach>
```

Comment: fileContents returns a Map<String, InputStream>

Answer (score 7):

If fileContents is a Map, then you should use `collections=#[payload.entrySet()]`. That way within the `foreach` you can do `#[payload.key]` and `#[payload.value]` (because the payload in each step will be an Entry).